# Testing of personal projects

Tags: web-development, testing, web-applications, websites

I'm developing a web based personal project that will hopefully be used by thousands.  Obviously prior to releasing it in the wild as Beta I was wondering,  are there any communities out there that will test my web app and provide feedback?  Free would be great, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: We're here, why not give it a run?

Comment: @Josh K beat me to it, in my answer +1. That makes 2 of us who are curious, @dave.b :)

Comment: Isn't that exactly what a beta period is for?

Comment: @Anna: More like an Alpha period. For development we do alpha testing among the dev team, beta testing among the production team, and release candidates on management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People here perhaps? And users at other stackexchange sites.

Maybe also people from a non-technical background, if, as you say potentially 1000s of users, some of those are likely to be non-technical and will have different issues regarding usability.

Friends? Family?

You might want to think of some incentives to motivate people to test your site: rewards, founder membership etc.

And also a criteria to test against.

Maybe you're already aware of the established user-acceptance testing discipline so forgive me if I've told you what you might already know so I won't say too much, except to say there are books, discussions and evangelists on the subject. O'Reilly - oreilly.com the book publish would be a good place to look for more ideas.

**Edit:**

Check out this book: "Effective UI: The Art of Building Great User Experience in Software"
http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154783/

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience. Find your target audience. Find people you know, people who will be honest. You have to have a pain in the butt friend who would love to tear your app to shreds. Though this answer seems light, watching a user use your app is the most beneficial thing i have ever done. My favorite test is to sit them down and give them no instruction. Figure out what they WANT to do.

Answer (score 1):

I use three stages of testing:

#### Alpha

Alpha testing is primarily done among the developers. It sounds like you're in this stage. Here people are responsive from a technical angle, they can identify errors and know what causes them along with fix recommendations. Programmers.SE might be the crowd you're looking for here.

#### Beta

Beta testing is done among your target audience. Advertise a beta period, keep it to a manageable size and have a public wiki / bug / issue tracker available.

#### Release Candidates

This is an optional step for developing applications. Here you would advertise to your target audience and beyond a potential release. Freeze the version number and consolidate features here. Limit work to bug fixing and minor UI issues.

Comment: Am keen on the alpha stage too, to test my app. How and where do I announce the app details on Programmers SE?

Comment: @Mamta: Why not post a question here?